# Can Ubuntu open .tgz archive from TotalCommander?

Tags: archive

I created .tgz archive via Total Commander on Windows, can I later open it on Ubuntu? And is it the same as .tar.gz? Thanks

Comment: The extension name does not matter in Linux. That is just for us humans to see what the file represents. If you have a program that can view a compressed tar file (ie. that would be with the "tar tvfz" command) software can open it. They tend to hook into the command itself.

Comment: -1 for asking hypothetical questions: http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

`.tgz` is the same as `.tar.gz`, just like `.jpg` and `.jpeg` represent the same file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a file extension has no meaning in Ubuntu. Ubuntu determines (at least should) a file's content by its [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), not by its extension. But .tgz and .tar.gz are used for the same purpose: To describe a gzip-compressed TAR archive.

As [TAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) is an open archive format, it can be read without problems on any system that supports it. Ubuntu does so - every .deb package is compressed as a gzipped TAR.

So unless you didn't apply any encryption etc., you shouldn't have any problems. If you're still not sure, boot Ubuntu into a live environment and find out.

---

Example: I copied a driver packed into a file ending in `.tar.gz` into two other ones ending in `.tgz` and `.foo`:

```
$ file DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz
DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sat Oct 12 00:22:20 2013
$ cp DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tgz && file DPO*tgz
DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tgz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sat Oct 12 00:22:20 2013
$ cp DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.foo && file DPO*foo
DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.foo: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sat Oct 12 00:22:20 2013
```

So as Shakespeare already wrote:

```
What's in a name? That which we call a rose
By any other name would smell as sweet.
    - Romeo and Juliet, II,2:1f
```

Name doesn't matter, at least as long as you're not using Windows.

Comment: Stealing my comment are we? >:-D

Comment: I assume you wrote your comment while I was writing my answer... Why stealing?

Comment: Mind the >:-D  :-)